# How to get OS disk related details from Azure Python SDK for a vm

Tags: python, azure, virtual-machine, disk

I am trying to get information specifially about OS disk of Azure VM via python sdk

I tried to get the information via

```
 disk_account_type =  vm.managed_disk.storage_account_type
```

but got below error:

```
AttributeError: 'VirtualMachine' object has no attribute 'managed_disk'
```

Where can i get OS Disk Name, Size and Encryption value and Storage account type for this OS disk specifically.
Edit : screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the code below to get them.

```
vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get("groupname", "joyvm1")

name = vm.storage_profile.os_disk.name
disk_size_gb = vm.storage_profile.os_disk.disk_size_gb
encryption_settings = vm.storage_profile.os_disk.encryption_settings
storage_account_type = vm.storage_profile.os_disk.managed_disk.storage_account_type

print(name, disk_size_gb, encryption_settings, storage_account_type)
```

[image]

**Update:**

If the `Encryption value` you mean is the `disk_encryption_set`, you could use the code below, it returns the disk encryption set resource id.

```
disk_encryption_set = vm.storage_profile.os_disk.managed_disk.disk_encryption_set
print(disk_encryption_set)
```

[image]

**Update2:**

```
disk_encryption_set = vm.storage_profile.os_disk.managed_disk.disk_encryption_set

if disk_encryption_set is None:
    encryption = "SSE with PMK"
else:
    encryption = "SSE with CMK"

print(encryption)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Encryption value i am looking at like "SSE with PMK " which is shown on azure portal

Comment: @asp Could you show the screenshot of that in your question?

Comment: @asp You could not get it directly via the sdk, by default the encryption is `SSE with PMK`, then the `disk_encryption_set` will be `None`, if it is `SSE with CMK`, it will return a resource id of the disk encryption set as mentioned in the update in my reply. So your option is to use a judgement, if the `vm.storage_profile.os_disk.managed_disk.disk_encryption_set`  is `None`, the `encryption type` is `SSE with PMK` .

Comment: I see that python and some other SDKs show size only when the VM is running. Is there a way to get over it for stopped VMs?